# Space of null title under icons of menu item

Tags: android

I used the menu item like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/tab_bookmarks"
    android:icon="@drawable/bookmark"
    android:title="@null"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/tab_shasha"
    android:icon="@drawable/shasha"
    android:height="54dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:title="@null"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/tab_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title="@null"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/tab_tv"
    android:icon="@drawable/tv"
    android:title="@null"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/tab_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/more"
    android:title="@null"/>
```

and this is one of the drawable tused in item above like android:icon="@drawable/tv" so this is tv.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_tv_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:bottom="13dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_tv"/>
</selector>
```

and I use this menu in bottomNavigationView like this:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.tab_bookmarks:
                                selectedFragment = BookmarksFragment.newInstance();
                                break;

                            case R.id.tab_home:
                                selectedFragment = AboutUs.newInstance();
                                break;

                        }
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

and everything work fine but as you can see the menu items they have icons but I set the title to "@null"
so the bottom bar have icons now and there are no texts below icon but it still have the space of empty title which lead to make icons smaller
so how can I set no title like make title space gone and won't take space and leave all of it for icon to be larger than now

this is a photo for my bottom bar:

[image]

you can see the space on null title under the icons so how to make all space for icon like the pink square around the tv icon to make it larger because I tried to change the width and height of items and other solutions but nothing work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this method:

```
public void updateBottomBar() {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
    if (menuView != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView menuItemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            ImageView icon = menuItemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        }
    }
}
```

It must be called when tab position is changed.

**Update**

There is a more beautiful solution, it works with the support library 28.0.0-alpha1:

```
 bottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED);
```

or

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" />
```

and remove your code `BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);`

Comment: please can you explain more

Comment: The above code is applied after initialization `bottomNavigationView`. He finds and centers icons.

Comment: so you mean I should keep my code as I wrote it and just add the method you talked about to the code too? @UgAr0FF

Comment: Thanks man I tried the code way but it doesn't work so I update the library to 28 and it works with amazing new solution, now the title hidden and the icons centered well but the icons still small in size so is there any way to make it bigger? if you can help me thanks a lot @UgAr0FF

Comment: Add this parameter `<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">24dp</dimen>` to the `dimens.xml` with the desired size, it will override the icon size.

Comment: `24dp` - default icon size